# No module named 'upwork.routers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, upwork-api

I have this simple imports that is failing with

```
    from upwork.routers.jobs import search
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'upwork.routers'
```

Ref: https://upwork.github.io/python-upwork-oauth2/routers/jobs/search.html
https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#jobs

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import upwork
from upwork.routers.jobs import search
```

I did

```
$ pip install upwork
$ pip list | grep upwork
upwork 1.0.22
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your own script named `upwork.py`? If it is, rename it to something else.

Comment: No, it's `upwork-search-jobs-API.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct PyPI package for [the `upwork/python-upwork` GitHub repo](https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork) is [`python-upwork`](https://pypi.org/project/python-upwork/), so

```
pip uninstall upwork
pip install python-upwork
```

and give it another go.

The [PyPI `upwork` package](https://pypi.org/project/upwork/) is someone else's [unrelated Upwork scraper](https://github.com/devEyosiyas/upwork_lib).

Comment: Taking into account "Ref: https://upwork.github.io/python-upwork-oauth2/routers/jobs/search.html
https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#jobs", he is looking for `python-upwork-oauth2` package. `python-upwork` serves legacy OAuth1 signed requests. Upwork doesn't release new OAuth1 keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `python-upwork-oauth2`.

Comment: 2 weeks to review my API key... -_-